# Return all fields in a SELECT query as strings

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a database which have around 100 tables. In all tables all the field has different datatype like int,string etc.Now requirement is.

**When I use Select query for any tables it should give me all the fields of  the particular table as String type. If select query can provide all the filed as string then I don't need to write `cursor.getInt()` for `int` datatype. everywhere I only need to use `cursor.getString()`.**

Please tell me such a select query that return all the field as String type.

Comment: but what is the issue using cursor.getInt

Comment: @Monica: I guess he wants to populate some UI, without regard to the type of each field.  I can probably think of a half-dozen other reasons why this might be useful.

Comment: @Monica I have autogenerated function which select data from all 100 tables and provide individual arraylist of all table's data. now in same function I need to write cursor.getString(columnname) and if data type is int then cursor.getInt(ColumnName) .but I dont know which field has int and which field has string. so I want every field as String.

Comment: [Cursor.getType(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getType(int)) can give you the type.

Comment: @Rajesh Cursor.getType is fine. but for that there must be  single data in table. without out single row of data it will not work.

Comment: I have not understood what you mean by *without out single row of data it will not work*. I will post an answer to show it in Java code (not SQL as you requested)

Comment: @Rajesh I mean there must be single record in the table

Comment: Why can't you check if there are records and then process? Typical alternate case handling. Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Hi @Nil you need to cast int to string in query like:: "select cast(some_integer_column as text) from some_table"

Comment: yes, it is partially  right answer. but I need all fields as text. and I don't want to write this 'cast(some_integer_column as text)' for every column. because there are some table has more than 100 fields.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code snippet below. The `getTableContents` returns an `ArrayList` containing another `ArrayList` or `String` data. The inner list is the contents of each tuple/row of the table in `String` format. The `getAsString` method contains the actual sauce of checking for data type and converting to `String` if necessary.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getTableContents(String inStrQuery, String[] selectionArgs){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rows = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    //Check database and open if required
    if(null == database){
        open();
    }

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(inStrQuery, selectionArgs);
    try {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();
            int columnCount = cursor.getColumnCount();
            for(int c=0; c< columnCount; c++){
                row.add(getAsString(cursor, c));
            }
            rows.add(row);
            cursor.moveToNext();                
        }
    }finally{
        cursor.close();
    }       
    return rows;
}

public static String getAsString(Cursor cursor, int colIndex){
    String retVal = null;
    if(null != cursor){
        switch(cursor.getType(colIndex)){
        case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
            retVal = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(colIndex));
            break;
        case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
            retVal = String.valueOf(cursor.getBlob(colIndex));
            break;
        case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
            retVal = String.valueOf(cursor.getFloat(colIndex));
            break;
        case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL:
            retVal = String.valueOf(null);
            break;              
        case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
            retVal = cursor.getString(colIndex);
            break;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```